# Element tree writing back to disk

Tags: python, elementtree

I parse a large xml file in python using

```
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')

#do my manipulation
```

How do I write back the xml file to disk exactly as I have read it, albeit with my modifications.

Comment: Have you even read the documentation?

Comment: Or is the point in the “exactly”? There are some differences that are not significant to the meaning of the XML that won't be preserved, so the output may not be binary equal even if you don't change it.

Comment: Nope. Sorry i tried using tree.write() which gave a file half the size. Getting the grasp of it now. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write

Comment: Yes, it does not by default *read* everything. You should ask a more elaborate question with the kind of things you need to preserve and example.

Comment: I need it to read and write back everything as in the original xml. I need to feed  the xml to a program and I am not sure what that program is expecting. I am only trying to tinker with data inside tags, not with the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

This was the first line of the input xml file

I added `tree.write("output.sbp", encoding="utf-16")` and now they are of the same size.